# JavaFx with JPA (Java 14 and JavaFX 14)

Tags: java, maven, jpa, javafx, jpql

I'm trying to write a programm with JavaFX(14.0.2.1) that can interact with a MySQL database. I already wrote the code to interact with the database and it is working. I used the libraries EclipseLink(3.0.1 because for some reason my module-info.java won't recognize it if I use 3.0.2) and jakarta.persistence(2.2.3) and mysql-connector(8.0.20). But as soon as I use these three libraries in a JavaFX project I get a error message.
So the JavaFX part on it's own works and the JPA part on it's own also, but as soon as I put them together they stop working.

```java
Sept. 01, 2021 9:29:05 AM javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNUNG: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named LOL
    at java.persistence/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
    at java.persistence/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at das.sad/das.sad.HelloApplication.getEntityManager(HelloApplication.java:63)
    at das.sad/das.sad.HelloApplication.find(HelloApplication.java:84)
    at das.sad/das.sad.HelloApplication.main(HelloApplication.java:41)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application das.sad.HelloApplication
```

My pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>das</groupId>
    <artifactId>sad</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sad</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>das.sad/das.sad.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My module-info.java

```java
module das.sad {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires mysql.connector.java;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires eclipselink;

    opens das.sad to javafx.fxml;
    exports das.sad;
}
```

Part of my persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence-unit name="LOL" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Comment: By the way, you can replace your multiple JUnit Jupiter dependencies with just one, [*JUnit Jupiter (Aggregator)*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) for convenience.

Comment: Your POM indicates that you are using Java 14 with JavaFX 14. But you should mention those versions in your prose.

Comment: And why don't you use the current version of Java/FX?

Comment: Perhaps you need to [open](https://www.sitepoint.com/reflection-vs-encapsulation-in-the-java-module-system/) your `das.sad` module to `java.persistence`.  That is just speculation on my part, I haven't tried it.

Comment: You state that you use `jakarta.persistence(2.2.3)` (I kept your typo), but I don't see the dependency in your pom.xml, instead, I only see you explicitly exclude `javax.persistance`, so I don't really know what you are doing.  Anyway 2.2 is outdated, for jakarta.persistence, for any new project you should try to use up-to-date libraries, especially if you use jigsaw modules as numerous old library versions are not compatible with modules.

Comment: I directly importet the jakarta.persistence as a .jar, because that was the version that I got from my college professor, whitch worked during his classes. But I also tried it with 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 but the latter I could not add to my module-info.jar and with 3.0.1 I still had the same problem as with the 2.2.3.